# Simple and short if clauses for combind statements

Tags: r, if-statement

TRUE/FALSE if clauses are easily and quickly done in R. However, if the argument gets more complex, it also gets ugly very soon.

For instance: 
I might want to execute different operations for a row(foo) dependent on the value in one cell (`foo[1]`).
Let the intervals be 0:39 and 40:59 and 60:100

Something like does not exit:

```
(if foo[1] "in" 40:60){...
```

In fact, I only see ways of at least two if clauses and two else statements and the action for the first interval somewhere at the bottom of the code. With more intervals(or any other condition) it is getting more complex.

Is there a best practice (for this purpose or others) with a simple construction and nice design to read?

Comment: I found it difficult to fully follow your question. are you talking about something in the lines of "switch" ?

Comment: @jorgusch - You will get a better response if you provide more of an example for your problem.  Try to provide some sample data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to generalize the question a bit too much, I guess. Happy, that Musa gave a really nice solution to the problem. I will keep it simple next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure, but I would suggest to use something like:

```
f <- approxfun(0:100,c(rep(1,40),rep(2,20),rep(3,41)),method="c")
fac <- f(foo)
tapply(foo,fac,FUN,...)
```

where you can use any function FUN.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally following your question.  Are you looking for a switch statement?  Have a look at this example:

```
ccc <- c("b","QQ","a","A","bb")
for(ch in ccc)
     cat(ch,":",switch(EXPR = ch, a=1,     b=2:3), "\n")
```